# Calculating $e^{ar}+e^{ar^2}+...+e^{ar^n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculate the sum,

$$e^{ar}+e^{ar^2}+...+e^{ar^n}\ \text{where} \ a,r\in \mathbb{R}$$

It's easy to calculate the sum when the powers of $e$ are in an arithmetic progression. How do we proceed when the powers are in geometric progression?

Comment: Arithmetic progression, geometric progression

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function

Comment: Note that $e^{r^2} \ne (e^r)^2$ !!!!

Comment: @lhf: this is finite, and should not be regarded as a lacunary function -- the functional equation does not apply, and for a fair number of $a$ and $r$ it does not converge when carried out to infinity.

Answer (score -1):

Let ${ar}^i=i\log m.$ Then the series becomes $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{ar^{i}}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{e^{i\log{m}}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{{m}^i},$$ which is a geometric series.

Comment: Except for the problem that $m$ changes from term to term.